# If $2\cos A=x+\frac1{x}$ and $2\cos B=y+\frac1{y}$, prove $2\cos(A-B)=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

> I have
>   $$2\cos A = x+ \frac{1}{x} \qquad\qquad2\cos B = y+ \frac{1}{y}$$
>   I have to prove that
>   $$2\cos(A-B)=\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}$$

I have solved it by finding $x = e^{iA}$ or $ x = e^{-iA}$ and $y = e^{iB}$ or $e^{-iB}$ from given two conditions.

Then I evaluated $\frac{y}{x}+ \frac{x}{y}$ by taking first $x = e^{iA}$ and $y = e^{iB}$, and it is also satisfied when $x= e^{-iA}$ and $y = e^{-iB}$

> But when I take $x = e^{iA}$ and $ y = e^{-iB}$, this seems to not satisfy the required proof. Why would this be the case?

Comment: Are $A,B$ real? How about $x,y$?

Comment: @kingW3 Nothing is given in the question regarding that.

Comment: @kingW3 Yes I have but I was wondering if this could be solved using pure trig. I saw another solution online using AM-GM but that would assume cos A and cos B to be +ve...which need not be true always right?

Comment: You could apply AM-GM on $2|\cos A| =|x+\frac1x|$ but this is assuming $A,B$ is real otherwise $\cos A$ need not be $\leq 1$.

Comment: If $A,B$ are complex then the equality doesn't need to be correct take $A=B$ and $\cos A>1$ then $x+\frac 1x=2\cos A$ has two solutions for $x$, if we take $x = x_1$ and $y=x_2$ then $2\cos(A-B)=2\cos 0=2\neq \frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1}$

Comment: I think you are right, yiu should get $2\cos(A+B)$ in the other case.

Comment: @Empy2 Yes I am getting that exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's nothing to exclude the case$$x=\exp\pm iA,\,y=\exp\mp iB,\,\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=2\cos(A+B).$$Indeed, the fact that the given information is preserved under $B\mapsto -B$ (due to the cosine function being even) prevents us ever distinguishing $A+B$ from $A-B$ in our inferences. The best we can say is that *there exists a choice of* $B$ with$$2\cos B=y+\frac1y,\,2\cos(A-B)=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}.$$

Comment: What if A and B were given to be real? How would I then solve this?

Comment: @Techie5879 It wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: ah, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

The only values of $x$ for which $\dfrac12(x+\dfrac1x)$ is less or equal to $1$ in absolue value (necessary for the cosinus) are just $1$ and $-1$ which is obvious.

In other words, in order to have $\cos A=\dfrac12(x+\dfrac1x)$ you do have necessarily $x=\pm1$ in which case the question is trivially verified.